# PHP Form Inserting \ Into Code

Tags: php, forms

I'm using a form to pull an iframe code from the user and insert it into another page. However, when the code is pulled in, it's inserting a "\" into the mix.

Here is the original code:

`<iframe src='http://listings.realbird.com/home-search-o/?rb_id=N7T5O2I2&bq=[item type:housing][location:@%22Reno, Nv%22][listing type:housing/sale][property type:/foreclosure]&orderby=price' frameborder='0' width='100%' height='2700' style='width:100%; height:2700px;'></iframe>`

Here is the code after the php file has processed:

```
<iframe src=\'http://listings.realbird.com/home-search-o/?rb_id=N7T5O2I2&bq=[item type:housing][location:@%22Reno, Nv%22][listing type:housing/sale][property type:/foreclosure]&orderby=price\' frameborder=\'0\' width=\'100%\' height=\'2700\' style=\'width:100%; height:2700px;\'></iframe>
```

Any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: use double quotes! It doesn't like those singles so it's escaping them... that is, if you have control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like magic quotes to me.  You could try replacing all instances of ' with &apos;

Or look into the PHP method [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/147880-does-php-5-automatically-addslashes/

Some PHP default configuration is automatically adding slashes on content submitted on your form so that it will be "safer" to work with it if you want to insert it into a database or something like that.

If you want to prevent that behaviour I think you can turn it off for your entire php application by using something like: set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php

Give it a try.

Comment: also if you read more you can see that this behaviour will disappear in newer php versions, so you might want to check your scripts on different php versions if it will be required to make sure it still works and doesn't throw you a deprecated notice